# What's the difference between global and local pointers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, global-variables

I have a small code something like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int *ptr1;
    int *ptr2;


  void some_function(void)
    {

    int B = 5;
    ptr2 = &B;
    }

  main (){
    int C, D;
    int A =10;
    int *ptr3;
    ptr1= &A;

    ptr3=ptr2;

    some_function();

    C = *ptr1 + *ptr2;

    printf("Sum of the numbers C= %d\n",C);

    some_function();
    D = *ptr1 + *ptr3;

    printf("Sum of the numbers D= %d\n",D);

  }
```

Why dont I get the result for D but get the result for C? I get the result for the print statement S`um of the numbers C=15` but nothing for the last print statement for D. What is the difference between local and global pointers ( I mean both ptr1 and ptr2 are defined global and ptr3 is define local)? Is the pointer assignment `ptr3=ptr2` valid? are there any significant difference with pointer to local variable Vs. pointer to global variable ?

Comment: You can't point to a local variable after the function returns.

Comment: You're seeing **undefined behaviour**; you're assigning `ptr2` to `ptr3`, but at that point, you haven't set `ptr2` to point at anything.  In fact, I would expect this program to crash on most systems.

Comment: What would you say `ptr2` is pointing to, once `some_function()` returns? Once the function returns, there is no memory location validly designated as `B` for `ptr2` to point to.

Comment: You forgot `main`'s return type, Skippy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ptr3 = ptr2;
```

`ptr3` is initialized with the value of `ptr2` which is `NULL`. It is `NULL` because you didn't initialize it and it has static storage duration.

then you do

```
D = *ptr1 + *ptr3;
```

You are dereferencing `ptr3` which is a null pointer: this is undefined behavior. The value of `ptr2` may have changed during your program, but `ptr3` is still a null pointer.

**EDIT:** For the sake of completeness (*well, sort of*):

```
void some_function(void)
{
    int B = 5;
    ptr2 = &B;
}
```

`B` object lifetime ends when the functions `some_function` exits. You cannot access `B` through `ptr2` after `some_function` has returned. It means:

```
C = *ptr1 + *ptr2;
```

also invokes undefined behavior because you are dereferencing `ptr2` which is an invalid pointer in this statement.

Answer (score 2):

`ptr3=ptr2;` **coped before the call of function**  `some_function();` so wrong address assigned to `ptr3` that is NULL because ptr2 is 0 (by-default value of global variable).

Do like this:

```
some_function();
ptr3=ptr2;
D = *ptr1 + *ptr3;
printf("Sum of the numbers D= %d\n",D);
```

Also, following code running correct because `ptr2` value is used after call of `some_function();` function.

```
some_function();
C = *ptr1 + *ptr2;
printf("Sum of the numbers C= %d\n",C)
```

Ooh!, Scope of variable `ptr2` points to local to some_function().

```
void some_function(void)
    {

    int B = 5;
    ptr2 = &B;
    }
```

Do like this:

```
void some_function(void)
    {

    int* B = calloc(1,sizeof(int));
    *B = 5; 
    ptr2 = B;
    }
```

Also don't forget to `free(ptr2)` after print statement;